# Apply only one confirmation dialog for all file and image inputs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I have few ImageInput and FileInputs and a confirmation dialog. Is there a way for all ImageInput and FileInputs to use on one confirmation dialog only? Rather have to create many confirmation dialogs to cater them.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Create,
  SimpleForm,
  ImageInput,
  ImageField,
  FileInput,
  FileField,
  Confirm,
} from 'react-admin';

export const PostCreate = props => {
  const [removeImage, setRemoveImage] = React.useState(null);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ImageInput 
          source="pictures" 
          label="Related pictures"
          validateFileRemoval={(file) => {
            const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              setRemoveImage({
                fileName: `Image: ${file.title}`,
                delete: () => {
                  resolve(true);
                },
                cancel: () => reject,
              });
            });
            setOpenModal(true);
            return promise.then((result) => true);
          }}
        >
          <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
        </ImageInput>
        <FileInput source="attachments_pdf" accept=".pdf">
          <FileField source="src" title="title" />
        </FileInput>
        <FileInput source="attachments_csv" accept=".csv">
          <FileField source="src" title="title" />
        </FileInput>

        <Confirm
          isOpen={openModal}
          title="Delete image"
          content={`${removeImage ? removeImage.fileName : ''} will be deleted`}
          onConfirm={() => {
            console.log('onConfirm');
            setOpenModal(false);
            removeImage?.delete();
          }}
          onClose={() => {
            setOpenModal(false);
            removeImage?.cancel();
          }}
        />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  )
};
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear as so far there is only one dialog (presumably that's what `<Confirmation>` is) component. Im guessing you are planning on adding more -- what are those use cases?

Comment: I plan to only use one <Confirmation>, rather than adding more. But not sure how to handle states for this case.